# Count unique child-nodes that hold specific substring

Tags: xml, xpath, xpath-1.0

I've got a small query on Excel's `FILTERXML` function and would like to return all parent `<t>` nodes that got more than 2 unique child nodes that contain the text property of it's parent. To visualize this:

```
<x>
  <t>A
    <s>A|x</s>
    <s>A|y</s>
    <s>B|y</s>
    <s>B|z</s>
  </t>
  <t>B
    <s>B|x</s>
    <s>B|y</s>
    <s>B|Z</s>
    <s>A|x</s>
  </t>
  <t>C
    <s>C|x</s>
    <s>C|y</s>
    <s>C|x</s>
    <s>A|x</s>
  </t>
</x>
```

So what I would like to return here would be t-node `B` since that's the only one that has more than 2 unique childres that hold their parents text property `B`.

Therefor I came up with the following expression:

```
//t[count(.//*[contains(.,concat(../text(),'|'))])>2]
```

This works fine to return `B` but also return `C` since it doesn't yet account for unique values. Therefor I tried to extend this expression:

```
//t[count(.//*[contains(.,concat(../text(),'|'))][.//*[not(preceding::*=.)]])>2]
```

But however, now it returns no t-nodes. Where did I go wrong in my extended expression and how can I fix this to only return `B` in this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, the wonders of xpath 1.0... It's doable, but is ugly looking:

```
//t[count(s[not(.= preceding-sibling::s/.)][contains(.,concat(../normalize-space(text()[1]),"|"))])>2]
```

Comment: Thanks for your work. Excel's FILTERXML somehow does not like: `s[not(.= preceding-sibling::s/.)]`. Is their anyway to rewrite this differently? I see it works on the xpath testers though, so thanks again. I think the issue lays in `s/.` to be specific.

Comment: @JvdV Unfortunately there's no other way that I know of. The reason we need this to begin with is that xpath 1.0 does not have a direct method for selecting unique values (xpath 2.0 and above use `distinct-values()` for that purpose, which makes it much easier).

Comment: Ok, I tweaked it so it works: `//t[count(s[not(.= preceding-sibling::*)][contains(.,concat(../text(),'|'))])>2]`. Could you confirm this would still yield correct results? My testing seems it does.

Comment: @JvdV No, it doesn't; I'm not sure how it manages to work in your testing, but in "standard" xpath, it raises a "required cardinality" error: `A sequence of more than one item is not allowed as the first argument of concat() (text("A"), text(""), text(""), ...) `. This, btw, was also the problem with the attempts in your question. The placement of both `concat()` and `contains()` is very sensitive, and the slightest deviation of either raises the required cardinality issue.

Comment: Well, for some reason that is what Excel needed. You can give it a go if you have excel 2013 or higher. I'll mark it as the answer. Btw it also worked on the online testers I tried. Thanks for your time.